# ASP.NET Core MVC + Entity Framework + GET + Array

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm doing some tests to take a project. I have been working with ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework relatively recently. I have a simple database in SQL Server to prove how it is:

[image]

In the test project I have a controller `TestController`; the code is this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WEBAPPHTTP.Models;

namespace WEBAPPHTTP.Controllers
{
    [Route ("api/controller[]")]
    public class TestController: Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("/api/values")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            using (TareasContext db = new TareasContext())
            {
                var listar = db.Tareas;
                var n = listar.Count();

                string[] array = new string[n+1];
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var otareas in listar)
                {
                    array[i] = otareas.Tarea.ToString();
                    i = i++;
                }

                return array;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong but the output is this:

in localhost/api/values:

```
["ahora",null,null,null,null]
```

It only shows me the last record of the database followed by a few NULL, this test the idea is that all the results are loaded in the array.

I'm sure it's a very early mistake, I hope you can guide me.

Comment: `i = i++;` looks _very_ strange and wrong. You assign `i` to `i` and then increment `i`.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what you want to do after this,  but if you just want to list out your items, you should be able to do something like this:

```
using (TareasContext db = new TareasContext())
        {
            return db.Tareas.ToList();

        }
```

That will give you the full list with all items in it with all properties, if you want just a part of your properties I would suggest to do a .Select as well.
Remember to do a where as well so you dont always return the full list (if it gets enourmus big)

Peace!

Answer (score 2):

You code is not efficient. This is the much cleaner version that does the same:

```
using (TareasContext db = new TareasContext())
{
    var result = db.Tareas.Select(x => x.Tarea).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

As I see the `Tarea` column is of `varchar` or `nvarchar` type. So, you don't need to cast it to string.